# nsfetchresultcontroller and external sync - possible bug 

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data

**SOLUTION**
answer was creasy but: it just necessary to place [self.tableView beginUpdates]; and [self.tableView endUpdates]; in correct place. nsfetchcontroller don't agree to place inside didChange :)

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}
```

I have class, which make changes in other moc, outside main context.
After changes is done, 2 objects going to be delete:

```
2011-12-21 11:05:06.599 snow[3200:20c1b] CLIENT CONTROLLER:
destination will removed with country:Afghanistan specific:Kabul
2011-12-21 11:05:06.712 snow[3200:20c1b] CLIENT CONTROLLER:
destination will removed with country:Afghanistan specific:Mobile -
AWCC
```

this cause to fire NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

```
2011-12-21 11:05:08.804 snow[3200:1bb03] DESTINATIONS LIST: DELETE : <NSIndexPath 0xb1f8f50> 2 indexes [0, 0]
```

but then, strange issues is going. Tableview start to get numberOfRows, and then:

```
2011-12-21 11:05:08.805 snow[3200:1bb03] Number of rows in section:0 for country:Afghanistan/Mobile - CDMA = 0
2011-12-21 11:05:08.805 snow[3200:1bb03] Number of rows in section:1 for country:Afghanistan/Herat = 0
2011-12-21 11:05:08.805 snow[3200:1bb03] Number of rows in section:2 for country:Afghanistan/Kandahar = 0
2011-12-21 11:05:08.805 snow[3200:1bb03] Number of rows in section:3 for country:Bahrain/Mobile - WiMax = 0
2011-12-21 11:05:08.805 snow[3200:1bb03] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:1030
2011-12-21 11:05:21.005 snow[3200:1bb03] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (6), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted). with userInfo (null)
2011-12-21 11:05:21.005 snow[3200:1bb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (6), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
```

here is current number of sections

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger count = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] count];
    return count;
}
```

Looks like nsfetchresultcontroller start delete stage, and forget to do it follow objects removing steps. Count is already 4 sections, but fetch request start to delete just one row.

For local removing, in self.managedobjectcontext, everything work fine with same code.
Here is fetch controller delegate:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            NSLog(@"DESTINATIONS LIST:INSERT to indexpath :%@",newIndexPath);
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            break;
        }   
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            NSLog(@"DESTINATIONS LIST: DELETE : %@",indexPath);
            @synchronized (self) {
                if ([self.sections containsIndex:indexPath.row]) [self.sections removeIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            break;

        }

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        {
            NSLog(@"DESTINATIONS LIST:UPDATE :%@",indexPath);
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            break;
        }

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        {
            NSLog(@"DESTINATIONS LIST:CHANGE MOVE from :%@ to %@ ",indexPath,newIndexPath);
            BOOL isOpened = NO;
            @synchronized (self) {
                isOpened = [self.sections containsIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            if (isOpened) {
                NSLog(@"DESTINATIONS LIST:OPENED CHANGE MOVE from :%@ to %@ ",indexPath,newIndexPath);

                [sections removeIndex:indexPath.row];
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                [sections addIndex:newIndexPath.row];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:newIndexPath.row]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
            } else { 
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; 
            }
        default:
            break;
        }
    }


    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}

self.sections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
```

Sync is passed from different thread and of course moc is sync all saves:

```
        moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [moc setUndoManager:nil];
        [moc setMergePolicy:NSOverwriteMergePolicy];
        //[moc setMergePolicy:NSRollbackMergePolicy];
        [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(importerDidSave:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:self.moc];

- (void)importerDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {
    //NSLog(@"MERGE in client controller");
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self.mainMoc mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
//        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finalSave:) withObject:self.moc waitUntilDone:YES];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isCurrentUpdateProcessing"];

    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(importerDidSave:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
```

**SOME UPDATE**

in case of delete just one object, which deleted inside (NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete is passed, fired NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:

```
2011-12-21 14:04:09.821 snow[5818:1bb03] DESTINATIONS LIST: DELETE : <NSIndexPath 0x933cb50> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2011-12-21 14:04:09.821 snow[5818:1bb03] Number of rows in section:0 for country:Afghanistan/Proper = 0
2011-12-21 14:04:09.821 snow[5818:1bb03] Number of rows in section:1 for country:Bahrain/Mobile - WiMax = 0
2011-12-21 14:04:09.822 snow[5818:1bb03] DESTINATIONS LIST:CHANGE MOVE from :<NSIndexPath 0x933bcb0> 2 indexes [0, 2] to <NSIndexPath 0x936ec10> 2 indexes [0, 1] 
2011-12-21 14:04:09.823 snow[5818:1bb03] Number of rows in section:0 for country:Afghanistan/Proper = 0
2011-12-21 14:04:09.823 snow[5818:1bb03] Number of rows in section:1 for country:Bahrain/Mobile - WiMax = 0
```

fetch result controller working more strange:

on

```
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

thinking about 10-15 seconds, and later do on same code EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
here is message trace:

```
#0  0x0222109b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00000850 in <????> ()
#2  0x00b580e3 in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport initWithTableView:updateItems:oldRowData:newRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] ()
#3  0x00971e3a in -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] ()
#4  0x0097d211 in -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] ()
#5  0x0097d23f in -[UITableView endUpdates] ()
#6  0x0002b277 in -[DestinationsListPushListTableViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] at /Users/alex/Desktop/snow/snow iphone/DestinationsListPushListTableViewController.m:1096
#7  0x01978121 in -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] ()
#8  0x015b3a39 in __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 ()
#9  0x0203b885 in ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 ()
#10 0x0203b7a8 in _CFXNotificationPost ()
#11 0x014f81aa in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#12 0x01894553 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] ()
#13 0x0192be3e in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] ()
#14 0x0188f9b3 in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] ()
#15 0x0188f269 in -[NSManagedObjectContext processPendingChanges] ()
#16 0x01863948 in _performRunLoopAction ()
#17 0x020449ce in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#18 0x01fdb670 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#19 0x01fa74f6 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#20 0x01fa6db4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#21 0x01fa6ccb in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#22 0x02a13879 in GSEventRunModal ()
#23 0x02a1393e in GSEventRun ()
#24 0x008eea9b in UIApplicationMain ()
#25 0x000029ed in main ()
```

enabling NSZombieEnabled don't show nothing,

Comment: Are you using different threads for the different MOCs? If so, make sure that you're performing `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on the correct thread (which should be the main one for the MOC that's wired to your UI via the `NSFetchedResultsController`).

Comment: @paulbailey of course, i do - i was updated question